# What's the proper way to manage allocated memory in the foreign language?

Tags: haskell, memory-management, ghc, ffi

My case is pretty simple: I have a C++ application and a Haskell library, and I just need to export from Haskell a function that would return a C string.

The issue is that the C string is originally a `String`, and to get a C string out of it I need to allocate storage which will have to be explicitly deallocated (Haskell's `free` or `finalizerFree`, as the documentation for [`newCString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Foreign-C-String.html#v:newCString) says).

What's a good way to handle that? Specifically I've got a few considerations:

Ideally I'd like to somehow let the Haskell runtime GC handle that, but I'm not sure how it could possibly know when and when not the memory is still needed by the foreign side. Is it possible?

If not, can I just call C's `free` or is the `CString` storage maintained by the Haskell runtime? if not I suppose I'll have to export Haskell's `free` as-well and call it from the foreign side, correct?

Comment: `CString` is just an alias for a naked pointer. Haskell will not manage its memory for you.  You can construct a [ForeignPtr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html) if you like, but it requires some care.  Any time you use the pointer, it must be contained entirely within a [`withForeignPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v:withForeignPtr) call.

Comment: If the string isn't too large (and doesn't mutate), you might be better off copying it so that one copy is owned by the foreign side and the other copy is owned by the Haskell runtime.  Otherwise, you may want to think of the foreign side handing ownership of the string to Haskell, i.e. the foreign side doesn't retain any references to the memory, and if it needs to do anything it calls back into Haskell to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You do have to deallocate the string: as you say, there's no way Haskell's GC can know if that's still needed in the foreign side.

Haskell's `free` is exactly equivalent to C's `free`. You can call either, from the side you prefer.

```
free :: Ptr a -> IO ()
free  = _free

foreign import ccall unsafe "stdlib.h free"    _free    :: Ptr a -> IO ()
```

I didn't check if this is mandated by the Haskell report + FFI Addendum, but I'd guess so.

Comment: One could also use `pokeArray` with a foreign-allocated buffer to be on the safe side.

Comment: "Haskell's `free` is exactly the equivalent to C's `free`" - That might be true, but care is in order. See http://blog.haskell-exists.com/yuras/posts/malloc-free-and-ffi.html